# How to group data while keeping all rows with max values Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This does not look hard but have not been able to find a solution. I have a df that looks like:

```
df = {'Name': ['MIR-10','MIR-10','LET-7','LET-7','LET-7','MIR-142','MIR-142','MIR-142'],
     'Type':['3prime','3prime','3prime','5prime','5prime','3prime','5prime','3prime']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
print(df)

      Name    Type
0   MIR-10  3prime
1   MIR-10  3prime
2    LET-7  3prime
3    LET-7  5prime
4    LET-7  5prime
5  MIR-142  3prime
6  MIR-142  5prime
7  MIR-142  3prime
```

I calculated the frequency of each `Type` for each element in `Name` using `groupby()` as below:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Name','Type'])['Type'].transform('count')
print(df)

      Name    Type  count
0   MIR-10  3prime      2
1   MIR-10  3prime      2
2    LET-7  3prime      1
3    LET-7  5prime      2
4    LET-7  5prime      2
5  MIR-142  3prime      2
6  MIR-142  5prime      1
7  MIR-142  3prime      2
```

Then what I would like to do `(in a SIMPLE solution)` is to keep the df if the `count` column is the maximum value for columns `Name` and `Type`.  The desired output should look like:

```
      Name    Type  count
0   MIR-10  3prime      2
1   MIR-10  3prime      2
2    LET-7  5prime      2
3    LET-7  5prime      2
4  MIR-142  3prime      2
5  MIR-142  3prime      2
```

I tried in several ways (like below) but could not get the target output.

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','Type'])['count'].transform(max)
print(df)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure if this is what you're looking for, but I determine the max count per Type and the max count per Name, and if the count in the row is equal to both maxes, then it should be kept:

```
df['max_name'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['count'].transform(max)
df['max_type'] = df.groupby(['Type'])['count'].transform(max)

df.query("max_name == count and max_type == count")

    Name    Type    count   max_name    max_type
0   MIR-10  3prime  2       2           2
1   MIR-10  3prime  2       2           2
3   LET-7   5prime  2       2           2
4   LET-7   5prime  2       2           2
5   MIR-142 3prime  2       2           2
7   MIR-142 3prime  2       2           2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is simple and powerful :)

Answer (score 1):

It is easier with `GroupBy.value_counts` and check `max` with `level`

```
new_df = df.join(df.groupby('Name', sort=False)['Type']
                   .value_counts()
                   .loc[lambda x: x.eq(x.max(level=0)) | x.eq(x.max(level=1))]
                   .rename('count'), on=['Name', 'Type'], how='right')
print(new_df)

      Name    Type  count
0   MIR-10  3prime      2
1   MIR-10  3prime      2
3    LET-7  5prime      2
4    LET-7  5prime      2
5  MIR-142  3prime      2
7  MIR-142  3prime      2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use the `assign` method to create temporary columns and filter for rows where the count is equal to the maximum count per group :

```
(df.assign(count = lambda x: x.groupby(['Name','Type']).Type.transform('count'),
           maximum = lambda x: x.groupby(['Name'])['count'].transform('max'),
           filter_ = lambda x: x['count'].eq(x['maximum']))
 .loc[lambda x: x.filter_, ['Name','Type','count']]
 )

    Name    Type    count
0   MIR-10  3prime  2
1   MIR-10  3prime  2
3   LET-7   5prime  2
4   LET-7   5prime  2
5   MIR-142 3prime  2
7   MIR-142 3prime  2
```